DataFrame from Iterators.product
In Julia, from a set of numbers numberset, I want to create a DataFrame that lists all combinations of k such numbers along with some function of each such combination, such as their sum. For example, if numberset = [3, 7], k = 2, and the function of interest is the sum, then I want to obtain the DataFrame



n1
n2
sum




3
3
6


3
7
10


7
3
10


7
7
14



(where order of rows doesn't matter to me, but it should generalize to higher k).
The challenge I run into is that Iterators.product gives me a matrix-like structure rather than a list of tuples, and I can't find an elegant way of getting it to return a DataFrame of the desired structure. Specifically, in the code below, the first DataFrame obtained from an Iterators.product has the right structure, but misses the sum column, while the second one is a representation of a matrix rather than the expected DataFrame. Is there a straightforward way of making the structure of the second one consistent with the first?
using DataFrames

firstdataframe = DataFrame(Iterators.product(Iterators.repeated(numberset, k)...))

seconddataframe = DataFrame([[x..., sum(x)] for x in Iterators.product(Iterators.repeated(numberset, k)...)], :auto)


Results:
firstdataframe:
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ 1      2
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     3      3
   2 │     7      3
   3 │     3      7
   4 │     7      7

seconddataframe:
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x1          x2
     │ Array…      Array…
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ [3, 3, 6]   [3, 7, 10]
   2 │ [7, 3, 10]  [7, 7, 14]


You could use vector comprehension to add the columns of x1 and x2 on to the end of the dataframe. Alternatively, you could simplify the code by simply building column by column. full explanations of both ideas are below

To convert your end dataframe to your desired result, you could use vector comprehension to iterate through each column of x1 and x2.
# Setting up your ending dataframe to work with
numberset = [3, 7]
k = 2

seconddataframe = DataFrame([[x..., sum(x)] for x in Iterators.product(Iterators.repeated(numberset, k)...)], :auto)

# Combine columns vertically
mydf = DataFrame(combined = [mydf.x1 ; mydf.x2])

# Add new dataframe col for each col in vectors (must all be same size)
for col in 1:length(mydf.combined[1])
    mydf[!, "data $col"] = [i[col] for i in mydf.combined[:]]
end

# remove original data
select!(mydf, Not([:combined]))
#=
julia> 
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ data 1  data 2  data 3 
     │ Int64   Int64   Int64  
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │      3       3       6
   2 │      7       3      10
   3 │      3       7      10
   4 │      7       7      14
=#

Another way you could do this, which would be more readable, would be to start by combining your variables into a singular column of tuples to then perform your function on, at which you point you would combine everything horizontally.
Since Iterators.jl is now deprecated, I have used the equivalent methods from its replacement in this new example, IterTools.jl. Luckily, IterTools has a function specifically for reducing arrays to a single column by performing a specified joining function. By using vcat as that function, we can combine all of the columns easily and performant...ly.
# Create your function. Summation is used as a placeholder

function myFunction(x)
    return x[1]+x[2]
end
numberset = [3,7]
k = 2

# Create k-length tuple of combinations of numberset vals
myVars = IterTools.product( repeat( [numberset], k )... )

#=
julia> collect(myVars)
2×2 Matrix{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (3, 3)  (3, 7)
 (7, 3)  (7, 7)
=#

# vcat all columns together
myVarsCollapsed = IterTools.reduce(vcat,myVars)

# Call function for each tuple in Vars
myCalculatedData = myFunction.(myVarsCollapsed)

# Create DataFrame with input vars
myDataFrame = DataFrame(
    myVarsCollapsed
)

# Append DataFrame with function outputs
myDataFrame[!, :Data] = myCalculatedData

#=
julia> myDataFrame
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ 1      2      Data  
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     3      3      6
   2 │     7      3     10
   3 │     3      7     10
   4 │     7      7     14
=#

This method will return the required output, although not necessarily in the desired order. You will want to sort myVarsCollapsed after its creation to specify the order.

julia> using Combinatorics, DataFrames

julia> numberset = [1, 3, 5];

julia> perms = permutations(numberset, 2);

julia> df = DataFrame(stack(perms; dims=1), :auto)
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x1     x2    
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      3
   2 │     1      5
   3 │     3      1
   4 │     3      5
   5 │     5      1
   6 │     5      3

julia> df.sum = sum.(perms);

julia> df
6×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1     x2     sum   
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      4
   2 │     1      5      6
   3 │     3      1      4
   4 │     3      5      8
   5 │     5      1      6
   6 │     5      3      8

